# What means Distinct in LINQ?

Tags: .net, linq

I have the following

```
Dim query = From city In myCountry.Cities
          From street In city.Streets
          Select New StreetInfo With {.Name = street.Name, .Index = street.Index}
          Distinct
```

Now. I remarqued that if I have multiple identical streets (having the same `Name` **and** `Index`), the StreetInfo list contains all that duplicates...

How should I specify the really distinct values for the resulting collection of StreetInfo values?

Say, the `StreetInfo` class is defined like this:

```
Public Class StreetInfo
  Public Property Name As String
  Public Property Index As Integer
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* override `GetHashCode` and `Equals` in `StreetInfo` - but that wouldn't be terribly nice in its existing form given that it's mutable. (You could create two instances which are equal one minute and then not equal the next. That often makes for a confusing debugging experience.) Alternatively, you could use an anonymous type, making sure you use readonly "key" properties:

```
Dim query = From city In myCountry.Cities
            From street In city.Streets
            Select New With { Key .Name = street.Name, Key .Index = street.Index}
            Distinct
```

Here the equality and hash code will be provided automatically by the compiler. This is then equivalent to:

```
Dim query = From city In myCountry.Cities
            From street In city.Streets
            Select street.Name, street.Index
            Distinct
```

See the [MSDN article on anonymous types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx) for more information.

If you definitely need `StreetInfo` values afterwards and you don't want to make it immutable, you could add another projection (Select) afterwards. I don't know if it's possible to append another Select clause *after* a Distinct clause in a single query, but you could use a second expression:

```
Dim query = From city In myCountry.Cities
            From street In city.Streets
            Select street.Name, street.Index
            Distinct

Dim query2 = From street in query
             Select New StreetInfo With {.Name = street.Name, _
                                         .Index = street.Index}
```

Comment: unfortunately, I can't use anonymous types, because I need to serialize the result... but that types are not serializable... Thanks for the Key, I didn't remark the difference...

Comment: @serhio: You could still use anonymous types for equality and *then* project into `StreetInfo`. But making `StreetInfo` immutable and overriding Equals / GetHashCode is a good alternative. (It would be useful if you'd state your requirements in the question, to avoid answers which won't actually help.)

Comment: I don't really understand what do you mean by use anonimous types and then projet into real objects... how that is possible, keeping the same query?

Comment: @serhio: You should be able to do a Select, then Distinct, then another Select. It's unclear to me whether you can do that in a single query expression, but you could certainly use multiple query expressions. Will edit.

Comment: Could you select the `StreetInfo` instance into the anonymous type, too? Then do a second query that just selects the `StreetInfo` references from the result of the first query? Seems like that would avoid having to create a bunch of new `StreetInfo` objects.

Comment: @JimMischel: This is going to create *fewer* `StreetInfo` objects - it's only creating one per distinct street. If we create one for each of the original streets, we'll have *at least* as many.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Looking at the code again, I don't know what I was thinking. And I didn't even have a drink at lunch.

Answer (score 5):

`Distinct` uses the default equality comparer, which means you'll have to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` on `StreetInfo` for it to work.

Comment: Or provide your own equality comparer to an overload of `Distinct`

Comment: Or use an anonymous type, for which the compiler will automatically generate the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods.

Comment: @JimMischel: Yes, that's exactly the approach I'd take, personally. The only drawback is that you can't pass such a collection around or return it in a nice way.

Comment: for the concrete example, I overrided the Equals, but not sure how to override GetHashCode... )

Comment: @Scott Rippey: where should I specify the comparer?

Comment: @serhio I expanded my comment into an answer.  See my answer for a great example of using a custom `IEqualityComparer`.  
As far as VB.NET syntax goes, I'm not sure if you can use a custom comparer with LINQ syntax, but you can use the "dot-notation" sytnax.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, using anonymous types is a good solution because the compiler creates the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods for you.  However, the problem is that you lose the references to your original objects (`StreetInfo`) and instead you get a list of distinct anonymous types.

Instead, you can use a custom `IEqualityComparer` to compare the original objects based on any custom field you want.  Below is a reusable `CustomComparer` that compares any object based on any custom criteria.

```
Public Class CustomComparer(Of TSource As Class, TCompareType)
    Implements IEqualityComparer(Of TSource)

    Private getComparisonObject As Func(Of TSource, TCompareType)

    Public Sub New(ByVal getComparisonObject As Func(Of TSource, TCompareType))
        If (getComparisonObject Is Nothing) Then
            Throw New ArgumentNullException("getComparisonObject")
        End If
        Me.getComparisonObject = getComparisonObject
    End Sub

    Public Function Equals(ByVal x As TSource, ByVal y As TSource) As Boolean
        If (x Is Nothing) Then
            Return (y Is Nothing)
        ElseIf (y Is Nothing) Then
            Return false
        End If
        Return EqualityComparer.Default.Equals(getComparisonObject(x), getComparisonObject(y))
    End Function

    Public Function GetHashCode(ByVal obj As TSource) As Integer
        Return EqualityComparer.Default.GetHashCode(getComparisonObject(obj))
    End Function
End Class
```

This allows you to write the following code:

```
Dim query = From city In myCountry.Cities
      From street In city.Streets
      Select New StreetInfo With {.Name = street.Name, .Index = street.Index}
query = query.Distinct(new CustomComparer(function (street) New With {Key.Name = street.Name, Key.Index = street.Index}))
```

This will return all distinct `StreetInfo` instead of returning distinct anonymous types.

(Note: Please excuse any VB.NET syntax issues ... I switched to C# before lambdas and anon types)

Comment: Thanks. Although your code does not compile at all )) I found what you mean and there is exacly my case on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx

Comment: Yeah, I converted the code from C# and I wasn't sure if it needed some modification to compile. It's a wiki, so feel free to fix it.